# How to change text in geometry nodes based on position

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a basic subdivided plane on which I distribute some points and I would like to have at each point a text with the point's Y position. The problem is, if i create text from string, that will only display one number everywhere, since the string is instantiated before the mesh exists. So i need to somehow get the instance of each point and the position for it and pass it to the Value to String node, but that does not seem to work with the Attribute capture node. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you attach your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com so we don't have to manually recreate it

Comment: @YousufChaudhry done!

Comment: May I recommend to view this video: [Visualize Numeric Attributes in Geometry Nodes](https://youtu.be/_W47HfoeFsg?si=jWDivnubx1kwtPLc) ?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

With Blender version 3.4 and *Geometry Nodes*, there is a Self Object node to reference itself.